# How to convert bitcoins to cash

Tags: development

I was informed by the company who sold me my bitcoins machine that I could convert my bitcoins to cash by using a mastercard so that I could make purchases or pay other bills using that mastercard, is this true and how do I do this?  If not, what is the best method to convert bitcoins to cash?

Comment: Off topic, but depends on your country is the answer. I've seen a visa: https://bitpay.com/card/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend going on [localbitcoin.net](http://yougotcustomers.in/partner/localbitcoins.net/) and sell your Bitcoins in person. You can also send them to a service such as Coinbase, but I highly recommend doing it in person as you won't pay for a cut.

Here are extra resources to help you throught your situation :

[4 ways to convert Bitcoins to Dollars](http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-Bitcoins-to-Dollars)

[A guide to selling Bitcoin in person](https://www.coindesk.com/information/sell-bitcoin/)